# Cannot implicitly convert type int[] to int?[]

Tags: c#, entity-framework

In my sample class it contain IdValues that is `int?[]`. The values is come from the other class that has an Id as a key field.

```
//Database class
public class SampleValues // this is a entity that i want to collect the deatil id
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int?[] SampleDetailIdValue { get; set; }
}

public class SampleDetailValues // this is the detail entity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}


// The error code
if (sampleDetails.Count > 0)
{
    sample.IdValues = sampleDetails.Select(s => s.Id).ToArray(); // << The error occurred this line.
}
```

The error is *Cannot implicitly convert type `int[]` to `int?[]`*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Cast in your projection:

```
sample.IdValues = sampleDetails.Select(s => (int?)s.Id).ToArray();
```

You were projecting an `int`, calling `ToArray` giving you an `int[]`, so simply project an `int?` instead.

There is alternatively the `Cast` extension method:

```
sample.IdValues = sampleDetails
    .Select(s => s.Id) 
    .Cast<int?>()
    .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

It can't be implicitly cast, but an explicit cast should work

```
sample.IdValues = sampleDetails.Select(x => x.Id)
                               .Cast<int?>()
                               .ToArray();
```